# jquery selector is not finding dynamically inserted input

Tags: jquery, dynamic, field

I have a form with money value input fields, the values of which are added together on keyup event and the total inserted into another input field. this works fine.

```
<table id="itemsqty"><tr><th style="min-width: 4em;">Qty</th><th style="min-width: 10em;">Description</th><th style="width: 4em;">Price</th></tr>
<tr><td><select name="qty[]" id="qty0"><option selected="selected">1</option>    <option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></td><td>    <input placeholder="Enter item name in here" type="text" name="item[]" id="item0" /></td>    <td><input class="itemprice" placeholder="Total price for this item" type="text"      name="itemprice[]" id="itemprice0" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><select name="qty[]" id="qty1"><option selected="selected">1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></td><td><input placeholder="Enter item name in here" type="text" name="item[]" id="item1" /></td><td><input class="itemprice" placeholder="Total price for this item" type="text"  name="itemprice[]" id="itemprice1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><select name="qty[]" id="qty2"><option selected="selected">1</option>   <option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></td><td>  <input placeholder="Enter item name in here" type="text" name="item[]" id="item2" /></td><td><input class="itemprice" placeholder="Total price for this item" type="text"  name="itemprice[]" id="itemprice2" /></td></tr>
<tr id="totalrow"><td><a href="javascript:;" id="addanotherlnk">Add another item</a></td><td style="text-align: right;padding-right: 7px;float: right;"><label for="gtotal" >Total:</label></td><td><input readonly type="text" name="gtotal" id="gtotal" value="£0.00" /></td></tr></table>
```

The value of the total input field (#gtotal) is updated using this script, and it works fine:

```
$('.itemprice').live("keyup", function (event) {
    var t = 0;
    for (var ip=0; ip <3; ip++){
        a = $('#itemprice'+ip).val();
        a = a.replace("£","");
        //t = t + a;
        t = Number(t) + Number(a);
    }

    //then add all values
    $('#gtotal').val('');
    var formattedMoney = '£' + t.formatMoney(2,',','.');
    $('#gtotal').val(formattedMoney);
});
```

Users can then add new fields using a link which fires this script:

```
$('#addanotherlnk').click(function(){
    //count number of items of same class
    var ic;
    ic = $('.itemprice').length;

    $('<tr><td><select name="qty[]" id="qty'+ic+'"><option selected="selected">1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></td><td><input placeholder="Enter item name in here" type="text" name="item[]" id="item'+ic+'" /></td><td><input class="itemprice" placeholder="Total price for this item" type="text"  name="itemprice[]" id="itemprice'+ic+'" /></tr>').insertBefore('#totalrow');
});
```

This works fine and adds a unique ID to the inputs/ However, the scripts which updates the totals does not seem to recognise this new input field. I know it is something to do with the fact that this is a dynamically added field, hence why I used jquery .live() method but this did not fix the problem.

All help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keyup handler is coded to loop through the first 3 elements only - you've hardcoded a limit of 3:

```
for (var ip=0; ip <3; ip++){
```

Instead you should loop through all elements with the "itemprice" class:

```
var t = 0;
$('.itemprice').each(function() {
    t += Number( this.value.replace("£","") );
}
```

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot about that for loop. I had intended to replace ip <3 with $('.itemprice').length; but I used your example instead. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if you have a group of elements like this that can be processed via their common class then you don't really need to give them an `id` attribute at all (though of course they'd still need a `name` for when they're submitted).

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your case is... u have harcoded 3 in your for loop... so it takes the value of 3 input and the dynamically added input is not actually added to the total...

i would suggest u to create a function that does the total calculation.....and call it in keyup function

try this:

```
function sumItemprice()  // function to calculate the sum
{
   var sum=0;
   $.each($('input.itemprice'),function(){ //select all ur input with the classname
     //add only if the value is number
      if(!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length!=0)
      {
          sum += parseFloat($(this).val());  // DO YOUR STUFF HERE (REPLACE or sumthing..)
      }
   });

  $('#gtotal').val(sum);
}
```

and the keyup function

```
$('.itemprice').bind("keyup",sumItemprice);
```

**NOTE**:  live() is deprecated, suggestion is to use on().

Comment: _"i would suggest u to create a function that does the total calculation"_ - The OP already has a function to do the calculation, that being the anonymous function passed to `.live()` - there's no point creating a separate function _and_ using an anonymous function to call it. You are correct that `.live()` is deprecated, but why did you suggest `.keyup()` which will create handlers only for elements that exist at the time?

Comment: yes... i agree.. creating a seperate function is not needed in this case... u can do what i did in the function inside the keyup function... but still there is no harm  in creating a function.... function might come handy, if OP has to do the total in other cases too instead of  writing the whole sum up thing again n again..... I prefer creating a function so i suggested.. :)

Comment: Sure. But if using another function then bind it directly with `.keyup(sumItemprice)` or, given the OP's requirement for a delegated handler, `$(document).on('click','.itemprice',sumItemprice);` - no need to still have an anonymous function if the only thing it does is call the other one.